# What is the pseudo-code for returning in a try block?

Tags: c#

The following code

```
class Animal : IDisposable
{
    static string Invoker()
    {
        using (Animal a = new Animal())
        {
            return a.Greeting();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
    }

    public string Greeting()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before");
        Console.WriteLine(Invoker());
        Console.WriteLine("After");
    }
}
```

produces

```
Before
Disposed
Hello World
After
```

Because this output in which `Disposed` comes before `Hello World`, I guess

```
using (Animal a = new Animal())
{
    return a.Greeting();
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Animal a = new Animal();
string buffer = null;
try
{
    buffer = a.Greeting();
}
finally
{
    a.Dispose();
    return buffer;
}
```

However, it is apparently not correct because the following error message:

> control cannot leave the body of finally block.

Then my final guess becomes as follows.

```
Animal a = new Animal();
string buffer = null;
try
{
    buffer = a.Greeting();
    return buffer;
}
finally
{
    a.Dispose();
    //return buffer;
}
```

However, I am still confused how can the `Dispose()` gets invoked if `return buffer` comes first in the sequence of execution.
Leaving the function body early makes the `Dispose()` must be invoked by something (other agent or thread or garbage collector or any hidden mechanism that I don't know in detailed). It is my imagination.
In addition, if `return buffer` comes first then the output should be

```
Before
Hello World
Disposed
After
```

### Question

Could you tell me how the compiler or internal mechanism invokes `Dispose()` while `return buffer` comes first that makes prematurely leaving the body of the function `Invoker`?

Comment: `try { buffer = a.Greeting(); } finally { a.Dispose(); } return buffer;`

Comment: Your final guess is correct. The `return` is inside the `try` block, not outside it.

Comment: See [the language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement) for what the using statement is equivalent too.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's what it does.

Comment: That's a much deeper subject.

Comment: @madreflection Well, `ret` IL instruction can not be inside `try` body.

Comment: @PetSerAl: True, but that's a detail of IL. It doesn't come into play until well after the textual translation has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is returned after the dispose and then written to the console.

The string is returned at the end of the method, so, after the dispose.

A "return" returns a variable after all has been done in the function.

It is like if a goto is made to go to the end of the method passing through all the finally blocks and then only here return the value.

In your case, your code is equivalent to this:

```
static string Invoker()
{
    string result;
    using (Animal a = new Animal())
    {
        result = a.Greeting();
        goto end;
        // a return here is like a "goto end"
        // done after invoking the Dispose()
        // while exiting the using block
    }
    // others things possible here
    // return anything_else_here;
    end:
      return result;
}
```

Here is the IL generated code by VS2017 (using .NET Reflector):

```
.method private hidebysig static string Invoker() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class ConsoleApp1.Animal a,
        [1] string str)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: newobj instance void ConsoleApp1.Animal::.ctor()
    L_0006: stloc.0 
    L_0007: nop 
    L_0008: ldloc.0 
    L_0009: callvirt instance string ConsoleApp1.Animal::Greeting()
    L_000e: stloc.1 
    L_000f: leave.s L_001c
    L_0011: ldloc.0 
    L_0012: brfalse.s L_001b
    L_0014: ldloc.0 
    L_0015: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    L_001a: nop 
    L_001b: endfinally 
    L_001c: ldloc.1 
    L_001d: ret 
    .try L_0007 to L_0011 finally handler L_0011 to L_001c
}
```

As you seen, the ret is at the end after the call to dispose.

Concretely, the code push the string in the stack and after returned to the calling method it is poped of the stack to retrieve the string.

In this example, the console writes something two times and wait for key, and then exit the method:

```
static string Test()
{
  try
  {
    try
    {
      return "a string"; // the string is pushed in the stack here
    }
    finally
    {
      Console.WriteLine("1");
      Console.ReadKey();
      // no other return allowed here
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    Console.ReadKey();
    // no other return allowed here
  }
}

// The method that calls Test() next pop the stack to retreive the string
```

It is the same thing that happens with a using block that calls Dispose at the end of this block while the value to return is in the stack waiting the pop of the caller.

The goto explanation is a muddy explantion and you can forget it if you understand IL, but it can help you to understand.

Comment: It is not an idea : il is what the compiler do to generate the IL (.net assembly language) code.

Comment: I added a code at the end of the answer that you can debug to see what's happen.

Answer (score 4):

The [Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement) says that a using statement of this form:

```
using (ResourceType resource = expression) statement
```

is equivalent to:

```
{
    ResourceType resource = expression;
    try {
        statement;
    }
    finally {
        ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Hence your using statement is equivalent to:

```
{
    Animal a = new Animal();
    try {
        return a.Greeting();
    } finally {
        a.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I can only guess why you think this is counterintuitive. Maybe because you think `finally` won't be reached because of the `return`? Well, the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-try-statement) also specifies that:

> The statements of a `finally` block are always executed when control
>   leaves a `try` statement. This is true whether the control transfer
>   occurs as a result of normal execution, as a result of executing a
>   `break`, `continue`, `goto`, or `return` statement, or as a result of
>   propagating an exception out of the `try` statement.

Comment: `goto` is still a thing? :p